# Including an existing file yields WordPress's 404 page

Tags: php, wordpress, http-status-code-404

I have a website that is running on WordPress. In the document root of this site, I have a directory in which I test PHP scripts unrelated to my WordPress installation. I notice that whenever I require or include a file that indeed exists, I get a 404. If I comment out the require statement, all is well. At first, this was because of syntax errors. But I cleaned it up and am no longer getting anything in the error_log file. What gives?

EDIT: found this in my main error_log: `malformed header from script. Bad header=X-UA-Compatible: ide.php`. I've never had a problem with this on other Apache servers.

Below is the offending script:

ide.php

```
<?php

require_once 'config.php';

if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    if (isset($_POST['command'])) {
        if ($_POST['session'] == '@') {
            session_destroy();
            header('Location: /area51/ide.php');
        } else {
            echo 'None';
        }
    } else {
        $smarty->assign('version', shell_exec("/home1/tylercro/local/python3/bin/python3 -c \"import sys;print('Python', sys.version)\""));
        $smarty->display('ide.tpl');
    }
} else {
    if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
        if ($_POST['username'] == 'user' && $_POST['password'] == 'password') {
            $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
        }
        header('Location: /area51/ide.php');
    } else {
        $smarty->display('ide-login.tpl');
    }
}

?>
```

config.php

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);

session_start();

if (!headers_sent()) {
    header('X-UA-Compatible: chrome=1');
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
}

require_once 'Smarty-3.1.8/Smarty.class.php';

$smarty = new Smarty();
$smarty->setTemplateDir('Smarty-3.1.8/templates/');
$smarty->setCompileDir('Smarty-3.1.8/templates_c/');
$smarty->setCacheDir('Smarty-3.1.8/cache/');
$smarty->setConfigDir('Smarty-3.1.8/configs/');

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a header issue. I had some syntax errors in the headers that I was sending out.